# What could be causing the document reader to crash?

Tags: 14.04, crash, evince

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and whenever I right click a pdf, the document reader crashes. I can't figure out what's wrong and I'd like some ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one PDF reader for Ubuntu.  I strongly recommend you try other readers before trying very hard to fix the one which doesn't work.  Just open the software center, type PDF, and then pick one.  "

It occurs to me that if you are using the google chrome or chromium browsers, you may be viewing using an online pdf viewer that may be failing for other reasons.  I've found google chrome to be unstable lately, and I'm not alone.